# How to change the size of an svg icon

Tags: html, css

Please see the snippet below. I have an svg icon whose width and height I've set to 80px each, however, the svg icon itself is not filling up that full size. How can I correctly adjust the size of an individual svg icon? Thanks!

```css
svg {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
   <svg width="80" height="80">
     <rect width="24" height="24" fill="none" rx="0" ry="0"/>
     <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M21 12C21 16.9706 16.9706 21 12 21C7.02944 21 3 16.9706 3 12C3 7.02944 7.02944 3 12 3C16.9706 3 21 7.02944 21 12ZM19.8 12C19.8 16.3078 16.3078 19.8 12 19.8C7.69218 19.8 4.2 16.3078 4.2 12C4.2 7.69218 7.69218 4.2 12 4.2C16.3078 4.2 19.8 7.69218 19.8 12ZM12 17C14.7614 17 17 14.7614 17 12C17 9.94968 15.7659 8.1876 14 7.41604V9.12734C14.9067 9.75982 15.5 10.8106 15.5 12C15.5 13.933 13.933 15.5 12 15.5C10.067 15.5 8.5 13.933 8.5 12C8.5 10.8106 9.09326 9.75982 10 9.12734V7.41604C8.2341 8.1876 7 9.94968 7 12C7 14.7614 9.23858 17 12 17ZM12 6C11.5582 6 11.2 6.35817 11.2 6.8V9.2C11.2 9.64183 11.5582 10 12 10C12.4418 10 12.8 9.64183 12.8 9.2V6.8C12.8 6.35817 12.4418 6 12 6Z" fill="#303131"/>
   </svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain what your SVG's original proportions were, but if you insert them to the last two parameters of the `viewBox` attribute on the `<svg>` tag, that'll give it something familiar to scale up to 80/80px from!

(I've guessed at 24/24)

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

> The value of the `viewBox` attribute is a list of four numbers: `min-x`, `min-y`, `width` and `height`. **The numbers separated by whitespace and/or a comma, which specify a rectangle in user space which is mapped to the bounds of the viewport established for the associated SVG element** (not the browser viewport).

(Emphasis mine)

```css
svg {
  background: pink
}
```

```html
<svg width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <rect width="24" height="24" fill="none" rx="0" ry="0"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M21 12C21 16.9706 16.9706 21 12 21C7.02944 21 3 16.9706 3 12C3 7.02944 7.02944 3 12 3C16.9706 3 21 7.02944 21 12ZM19.8 12C19.8 16.3078 16.3078 19.8 12 19.8C7.69218 19.8 4.2 16.3078 4.2 12C4.2 7.69218 7.69218 4.2 12 4.2C16.3078 4.2 19.8 7.69218 19.8 12ZM12 17C14.7614 17 17 14.7614 17 12C17 9.94968 15.7659 8.1876 14 7.41604V9.12734C14.9067 9.75982 15.5 10.8106 15.5 12C15.5 13.933 13.933 15.5 12 15.5C10.067 15.5 8.5 13.933 8.5 12C8.5 10.8106 9.09326 9.75982 10 9.12734V7.41604C8.2341 8.1876 7 9.94968 7 12C7 14.7614 9.23858 17 12 17ZM12 6C11.5582 6 11.2 6.35817 11.2 6.8V9.2C11.2 9.64183 11.5582 10 12 10C12.4418 10 12.8 9.64183 12.8 9.2V6.8C12.8 6.35817 12.4418 6 12 6Z" fill="#303131"/>
</svg>
```